# Область видимости переменной Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возникла проблема с глобальной переменной. Каждая функция должна срабатывать при определенном значении b(0 или 1). При увеличении её внутри первой функции, не срабатывает вторая. Вопрос: почему и как пофиксить? Спасибо

```
b = 0;
function cross() {
$('.box').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $('#x').attr('src'));
    b++;
});
}

function zero() {
$('.box').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $('#o').attr('src'));
    b--;
});}

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (b == 0) {
        cross();
    } else if (b == 1) {zero();}
});
```

Comment: что есть - "должна срабатывать при определенном значении"? сама что ли? вызывайте ее, тогда она сработает. `$(document).ready` вызывается один раз при загрузке страницы.

Comment: @gmate Вы устанавливаете обработчик события click только для первой функции.

Comment: Если b == 0, то должна срабатывать cross(); Если b == 1, то zero();
Вообще мне нужно переключать эти функции по очереди, вроде как: 
cross(), потом zero(), потом cross()
Крестики-нолики :D

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - причем обе функции навешивают обработчики на одну и ту же кнопку.

Comment: @Igor там 9 кнопок с классом box

Comment: плохо дело - :(

Comment: @Igor подскажите пожалуйста, уже сил нет
Нужно чтобы по первому клику на любой из блоков в нем замещалась картинка(крестик), по второму клику на другой блок(нолик) и потом все повторяется
Хотя бы на словах :((

Comment: приду домой - напишу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
      var move = "X";
      $("td").click(function(){
        var old = $(this).text();
        if (old != "X" && old != "O") {
          $(this).text(move);
          move = (move == "X")? "O" : "X";
        }
      });
    
      $("#btnClear").click(function(){
        $("td").text("");
        move = "X";
      });
    });
```

```css
    td 
    {
      width:40px;
      height:40px;
      text-align:center; 
      vertical-align:middle;
      font-size:x-large;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
    
    <table border=1 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2>
      <tr><td/><td/><td/></tr>
      <tr><td/><td/><td/></tr>
      <tr><td/><td/><td/></tr>
    </table>
    
    <br/>
    
    <button type="button" id="btnClear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!